# boot menu is displayed for just 1 sec

Tags: boot, grub2

I have windows 10 installed on my computer (without UFED), and today I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside. After the first boot (with 10 sec. delay), the boot menu is displayed for only 1 second, and the keyboard does not work in that second, as if the first option is already selected. Any solution for going back to 10 sec. boot menu? I've already tried boot-repair and it didn't work.

Here is my grub file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Everything else in the file has a # in front.

Comment: On Windows 10, do you have any software that came with your motherboard that allows for any customization?

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/etc/default/grub` file.  Place the time in seconds in the `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` option.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update                                                                                       
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.                                                                                                                                  
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:                                                                                              
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'                                                                                                              

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"                                                                                                                                
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Activate this change by running:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've checked grub.cfg and everywhere where TIMEOUT appears, the value already is 10.         
Here is  part of the file (i think Boot-repair messed with it):
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

Comment: Add this `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT` to the grub file then update grub.  I added it to the answer so that you can see it in context.

Comment: Ok, so my file looks like this:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Unfortunately  it didn't change anything. Do you have any ideas what it could cause this behavior? Or what can i do to help diagnose this problem?

Comment: @j.bravvo I can't make out what you have in your grub by the comment message.  Can you edit your question and append the text there?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me. I've added the content of the grub file in the first post.

Comment: @j.bravvo Sure thing... it's a pleasure.  Give me a little while to study and test other  possible culprits.